# Ajax Json attributes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to Json/jquery/javascript and just stick with this problem.
I have got an Ajax PUT call that sends some data to server and gets back a different response json.
Now problem is that I cant access attributes of resposne. 
Please do not mark Duplicate as I have already applied whatever I already found on stackoverflow, like setting datatype & Content-type.
I also tried json.parse however the statement gets ignored which I presume is because its already a Json.

```
            request = $.ajax({
            url: reporturl,
            type: "PUT",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/json" );       

            }
            });
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert("Wow, it worked!");
            alert(response); //returns [object object] seems ok
            if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
            alert("is json"); //returns yes, seems ok
            }
           var fileJSON = response.Criteria;
           alert(fileJSON); //returns undefined
```

Now: 
1) jqXHR.responseJSON is returning TRUE.
2) "response" is valid json as per json validation tools.
And response looks like: (the doubling of elements like Criteria within Criteria etc is desired and I assume shouldn't cause this problem.)

```
{
"response": {
    "Criteria": {
        "Criteria": [
            {
                "name": "UserRepCode1",
                "value": "XX"
            },
            {
                "name": "UserRepCode2",
                "value": "YY"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Files": {
        "Files": [
            {
                "fSeq": 0,
                "filetype": "spooler",
                "filetext": "XXX X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk \r\n\r\nUser defined report :                            \r\nClient From : \r\nClient To : \r\nEstate From : \r\nEstate To : \r\nManager From : \r\nManager To : \r\nProperty From : DLO REVOD Road DLO REVOD Road, DLO REVOD Road999, DLO REVOD Road2\r\n : Aberdeen, Grampian, SE10 7TZDLO REVOD Road DLO REVOD Road\r\n : DLO REVOD Road999, DLO REVOD Road2, Aberdeen, Grampian\r\nCurrency Type From : Pounds SterlingPounds Sterling\r\nCurrency Type To : Pounds SterlingPounds Sterling\r\nS/C Period : 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled-00101/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled-001\r\nBudget Detail : Expense ClassExpense Class\r\nSubTotal By Schedule : Yes \r\nSubTotal By Expense Class : No \r\nSubTotal By Expense Category : No \r\nNominal/Gross : Nominal Nominal\r\nDisplay Transaction : No \r\nActual Expenditure : Yes \r\nPre-Payments : Yes \r\nAccruals : Yes \r\nOverhead Recovery : Yes \r\nConvert Currency : No \r\nInc Property Budgets : No \r\n\r\nOutput To : Spool\r\nHeader : Yes\r\nOrientation/Font : Portrait, Selected\r\n \r\nMKDEBUG10 Email To : \r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : GROSV001 LTD(TA)\r\nEstate : 000000000338 Park, een\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unrec\r\n\r\n Nomture BudDiff\r\n To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\n\r\nProperty: 000100 DLO REVOD \r\nSchedule: 01 rty \r\n----------------------------------------------------\r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : DLO\r\nEstate : 000000000338 DLO, PSO\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled\r\n\r\n XLRO\r\n To Date For Period To Date To Date To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : DLO\r\nEstate : 000000000338 DLO, PSO\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled\r\n\r\n XLRO\r\n To Date For Period To Date To Date To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : DLO\r\nEstate : 000000000338 DLO, PSO\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled\r\n\r\n XLRO\r\n To Date For Period To Date To Date To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : DLO\r\nEstate : 000000000338 DLO, PSO\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled\r\n\r\n XLRO\r\n To Date For Period To Date To Date To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nDLO X3.07 - 22/12/2014 17:03 mk Page: 0\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\nClient : DLO\r\nEstate : 000000000338 DLO, PSO\r\nPeriod : 001 01/01/2012 - 31/12/2012 Unreconciled\r\n\r\n XLRO\r\n To Date For Period To Date To Date To Date\r\n__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\r\n\r\n10 Expense Class 10 0.00 720.00 720.00 -720.00 -100.00%\r\n --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------\r\nTotal Schedule: 01 Property 0.00 720.00 720.00 -720.00 -100.00%\r\n --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------\r\n =============== =============== =============== =============== =========\r\nTotal Period/Prop: 001 0.00 720.00 720.00 -720.00 -100.00%\r\n =============== =============== =============== =============== =========\r\n =============== =============== =============== =============== =========\r\nGrand Total for Currency GBP 0.00 720.00 720.00 -720.00 -100.00%\r\n =============== =============== =============== =============== =========\r\n"
            }
        ]
    },
    "UserMessages": {
        "UserMessages": []
    }
    }
    }
```

Now I am in dilemma that how should I retrieve individual attribute like criteria, files and messages for further processing.
Please help.

Comment: `console.log(response);` Use the power of the console! ditch those alerts!

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I am aware console is better, however in actual code I am using neither, I need to display the content in a new window(its huge data, here is only a snapshot).

Comment: Right, but by using the console.log, you would be able to see the actual structure of `response`, which should be enough to tell you how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is your variable that holds the object, not the first key in the object.

You would need to reference the first key

```
var fileJSON = response.response.Criteria;
```